# Display Image with 50% width and 100% height

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, image, format

I'm trying to make a Rating System for my Forum and so I work with Star-Images for each Average Rating.
What I'd like to do is to display half of such a Star if a User has e.g. an Average Rating of 4.5.
When I design the Divs in CSS and change the width with document.getElementById('foo').style.width = "50%"; it works like a charm, but when I do it like that:

my View:

```
<div id="half"><%= image_tag('../images/icons/rating_3.gif', options = {:style => 'width: 50%; height: 100%;'}) %></div
```

CSS:

```
#half {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

I'm getting the whole star resized to 10px width but I only want 50% width of the image for a half star.

What I get:

Any suggestions?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you have to right like this

```
  #half {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position:50% 0;
overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the image as the background image of a new div, of which you set the width 50%

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `<img>` tags handle their width differently than `<div>` tags, as you are finding out. Use a `<div>` and then style it instead:

```
div.half {
   overflow: none;
   width: 10px;
   height: 20px;
   background-image: url('star.gif');
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Use `class="half"` instead of an ID so that you can reuse this over and over on the page.